# Масштабирование Graphic в C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал в отдельном окне Graphics и рисую в нем приходящие координаты точек (от usb устройства).

Непонятные ситуации:

1. Видимая область объекта Graphics ограничена, и я не знаю как ее менять, изменял бы по размерам окна сразу.
2. Можно изменить видимую область с помощью метода `Graphics.FromImage()`, делаю так:

   ```
   public Graphics gra;  
   Size sizeScreen = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize;  
   Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(sizeScreen.Width, sizeScreen.Height);  
   gra = Graphics.FromImage(bit);
   ```

Но при рисовании ничего не происходит.

В лучшем случае у меня должны даже нарисованные круги масштабироваться, в зависимости от размеров окна.

Буду рад хорошим примерам, возможно другим средствам, библиотекам масштабирования, возможно даже не на шарпе!

Comment: У вас есть размер области, в которой должны рисоваться круги? Иначе нечего будет масштабировать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: посмотрите мой ответ [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479439/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-gdi/479442#479442)

Answer (score 1):

Переопределите метод [OnPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint(v=vs.90).aspx), например, у формы. И рисуйте на ней, что хотите:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Draw(e.Graphics);
    }

    // ваш метод отрисовки координат
    private void Draw(Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(50, 40, 200, 100));
    }
}
```

Видимая область будет размером формы. Так что ничего менять не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

> Создал в отдельном окне Graphics и рисую в нем приходящие координаты точек (от usb устройства).

Предположим, что вы хотите выводить точки прямо на поверхности формы.
Для этого, когда получаете данные, их надо сохранить, например, в массиве. 
И после этого вызвать `this.Invalidate()` у формы.
А для вывода точек надо у формы переопределить метод `OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)`. 
В нем надо прочесть данные из массив точек. Взять `e.Graphics` и вывести в него изображения точек.

Для вывода графиков лучше использовать [Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx).