# Как правильно рисовать с использованием GDI+?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

Проблема в том, что когда я сворачиваю\разворачиваю программу, все нарисованное мной пропадает. Я понимаю что можно создать обработчик события OnRoadPaint, но в моем случае это очень неудобно. Есть какой-то подход, чтобы можно было раз нарисовать фигуру, и она не пропадала бы?

```
Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();
graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(233, 67, 254, 504));
graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(233, 67, 254, 504));
```

Comment: рисовать надо в Graphics, который передается в OnPaint

Comment: Если так делать то мне нужно запоминать все предыдущие фигуры которые рисовались, и рисовать их повторно. Я же хочу рисовать не в обработчике OnPaint, а в каком то своем методе.

Comment: Разумеется, именно так программы и работают

Comment: @Lightness _"Я же хочу рисовать не в обработчике OnPaint, а в каком то своем методе."_ -- значит надо рисовать в Bitmap и его выводить в OnPaint.

Comment: А можно какой-нить пример? С Bitmap не приходилось еще работать.

Comment: @Lightness _"А можно какой-нить пример? С Bitmap "_ -- добавил в  ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> рисовать не в обработчике OnPaint, а в каком то своем методе

```
public class Picture : Control {
  public Picture() {
     var bl = new BindingList<Rectangle>() { RaiseListChangedEvents = true };
     bl.ListChanged += (s, e) => {
        image = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image)) {
           foreach (var r in Rectangles)
              g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, r);
        }
        this.Invalidate();     // вызовет OnPaint
     };
     this.Rectangles = bl;
  }
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
     base.OnPaint(e);
     if(image != null)
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(image, 0, 0);
  }
  public readonly IList<Rectangle> Rectangles;
  Bitmap image;
}

var f1 = new Form();
var p = new Picture() { Parent = f1, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
var r = new Random();
new Button() { Text = "Add", Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Parent = f1 }
  .Click += (s, e) => 
    p.Rectangles.Add(new Rectangle(r.Next(0, p.Width-10), r.Next(0, p.Height-10), 10, 10));
f1.ShowDialog();
```

---

Если выводится много графики, возможно мерцание при перерисовке.
В такой ситуации надо в форме переопределить свойство

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
   get {
      CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
      cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  //  WS_EX_COMPOSITED
      return cp;
   }
}
```

и в конструкторе контрола/формы указать

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint 
        | ControlStyles.UserPaint 
        | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Запоминайте все фигуры, рисуя их заново в OnPaint.

Или создание Image (точнее, Bitmap) нужного размера, положите его в поле класса, и рисуйте на нём. Создать Graphics из существующей картинки можно вызовом `Graphics.FromImage`. А в OnPaint отрисовывайте на форме этот Image.

В качестве полуготового решения - можете положить на форму [`PictureBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx) вместо ручной отрисовки Image.

Answer (score 1):

Также посмотрите GraphicsPath. В нем удобно запоминать графические примитивы в векторном представлении для последующего рисования.

Тут есть еще один пример переопределения OnPaint https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471375/198316